# How to display Edittext hover text on touch?

Tags: android, android-edittext, hover

I am working on one project and I want to display hint on edittext when user will touch on edittext shown like below image.

EDIT
Need to popup block, which show hint about EditText onTouch event of EditText.

[image]

Comment: Show your code also . Please clear your question what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (hasFocus) {
                    editText1.setError("Wrong input!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use editText1.setError() then you can use **PopupWindow** and attach with your editText1 wherever by specifying anchor position

like popupWindow.showAsDropDown(editText1);

Answer (score 0):

edittext.seterror("Text you want to show");